# Latex double quote without triggering an umlaut

Tags: latex, babeljs

I have a little bit of a problem with a written assignment in german. I have a definition I need to quote, which starts with an "A". I guess it gets replaced by babel package to look like an "Ä".

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\section{Definition}

\todo[inline, color=yellow!30]{\textit{\"Antisemitismus}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way I miss here, to prevent Babel package to replace the "A" in this specific instance? As you can see I tried with a backslash for masking the double quote, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ngerman [documentation](https://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/German.html) provides an answer to this in the section *Sonderzeichen*. As you realized the `"` are overwritten in babel.

However, you can use for example:

```
    \textit{\glqq Antisemitismus\grqq} % Double quotation marks
    \textit{\glq Antisemitismus\grq} % Single quoation marks
    \textit{\dq Antisemitismus\dq} % Double upper quotation marks.
```

Note the former two versions use the german formatting, where quotation marks start at the bottom of the line.